# Why, Spring Transactional, why? (UnexpectedRollbackException)

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, transactions

I really struggle with spring Transactional and need your help.
I used to be Oracle Developer so I have some understanding and habits with transaction processing.

My Spring application written on kotlin and use PostgreSQL database, but I think it does not matter at all.
And spring Transactional annotation does not lay on them.

Could you please explain how to realize this scenario and not fail with **UnexpectedRollbackException**.
I try to explain my question with pseudo code based on pl/sql

```
-- DocumentService
begin
  begin
    savepoint sav_agent;
    l_agent:= add_agent(); -- method in AgentService
  exception when others then
    rollback to savepoint sav_agent;
    l_agent := DEFAULT_AGENT;
  end;
  
  add_payment(l_agent); -- method in PaymentService
end;
```

a) I want to add agent, if possible and always add payment.
b) But if add payment fails, I do not want to add agent.

Logically, I add Transactional on each of two methods. Common method in `DocumentService` is Transactional too.
Each methods in `AgentService` and `PaymentService` do some checks and can throw any exception.
So I use `rollbackFor = [Throwable::class]` for any Transactional.

But if add_agent fails and add_payment - does not, I catch UnexpectedRollbackException.
I understand this exception and what it means, but I don't understand why anyone can need such behaviour...
If I add `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` on `AgentService` - there is no UnexpectedRollbackException, but AgentService commits anyway, so my "b" is not realized.
Second problem is `REQUIRES_NEW`-Transactional uses one more connection from my pool.
Third problem of `REQUIRES_NEW` - if I do some insert before add_agent - I cannot use it before add_agent, because it is another transaction and even connect.

I found this article https://dzone.com/articles/transaction-savepoints-in-spring-jdbc about savepoints.
But `JdbcTemplate` and `TransactionTemplate` not work when I using Transactional.
So I can realize fully manual transaction processing, but I want somethig more basic and convinient.

Third solution  `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)` fails with
`org.springframework.transaction.NestedTransactionNotSupportedException: JpaDialect does not support savepoints - check your JPA provider's capabilities`
in Hybernate.

I read spring docs and a lot of articles and Stackoverflow answers,but I really don't have understanding.
Please help me understand and solve my problem (I think this is not problem but basic functionality and I miss something extremly simple...)

Comment: Read that article, https://reflectoring.io/spring-transactions-and-exceptions/ . Are you interested in "noRollbackFor " instead of "rollbackFor" ? ( You want to prevent rollback , but use "rollbackFor" (that annotation doing opposite thing) , is that ok?)

Comment: Good article, but it confirms my misunderstanding.
In my example I want to fully rollback **add_agent** (it contains multiple inserts) at any exception, so I add `rollbackFor = [Throwable::class]`.
But I want to suppress this exception and commit some other information in add_payment.

If I add noRollbackFor, this may cause partially commit of **add_agent** and it breaks transactionality meaning.

Comment: I'll upvote your question (dont know the solution, but interested in it)

Answer (score 0):

Seems I find the solution: `isGlobalRollbackOnParticipationFailure = false`

Disabling this global parameter makes transaction behaviour as I expect.
Accoing to it's documentation disabling it is not very recommended, but why not, if it works?
I don't find a lot information about best practices, so I'll give this solution a try:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class MyCustomApplication(
    private val applicationContext: ApplicationContext,
) {
    init {
        val trm = applicationContext.getBean("transactionManager", AbstractPlatformTransactionManager::class.java)
        trm.isGlobalRollbackOnParticipationFailure = false
    }
}
```

Maybe anyone find this helpful or anyone tell me why it is wrong.